# Как организовать миграцию базы данных на продакшене?

Tags: php, symfony2, doctrine2, миграция

Здравствуйте!

У меня возник такой вопрос:
Как организовать процесс накатывания боевой базы данных при разворачивании проекта?

За скобками оставим обновление кода, зависимостей и тд.

А подробности такие:

```
Symfony 2.8.6 + MigrationsBundle + DataFixturesBundle + Mysql
```

Схемы базы лежат в миграциях, основные данные базы для проекта загружаются в фикстурах.
Также есть продакшен база с товарами, заказами и т.д.

Разворачиваю базу в тестовое состояние я таким образом:

```
php app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load
```

После чего мне нужно на эту базу накатить актуальные данные из продакшен базы, и вот тут-то возник затык.
Просто сделать дамп и накатить его не получится из-за того, что в продакшен базе уже есть исходные записи, которые создаются фикстурами, и при импорте вылетят ошибки типа duplicated.

Прошу поделиться опытом о том, как решаются подобные задачи, или кинуть мне какой-то полезный линк.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Фикстуры не нужны в продакшене. Фикстуры могут понадобится, чтобы развернуть дев или тест окружение, а на продакшене им делать нечего.

Миграции тоже - нулевая точка отсчета у них должна совпадать с актуальной структурой данных на продакшене. Т.е. первая миграция не создаёт базу, она делает первое изменение, которые нужно в уже живой БД.

Иногда мы делали первую миграцию, которая создает первоначальную структуру. Но тогда нужно сначала в ручную на продакшене внести запись о том, что эта миграция там уже выполнена.

Поэтому при каждом деплое нужно только `php app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate`

Comment: По фикстурам понятно.

Comment: Так как проект писался с нуля, исходной базы нет. А вся разработка шла через миграции. То есть я получаю актуальную схему базе просто делая миграцию. Получается исходные данные, такие как настройки мне нужно добалять в миграциях, а на проде просто накатывать миграцию, предварительно сделав дамп(перестраховка).

Comment: Да, всё так. Какие-то нулевые данные, как валюты, города, страны и пр. - добавляются в миграции тоже.

Comment: @Victor фикстуры предназначены для заполнения базы тостовыми данными, что бы потом протестировать приложение опираясь на эти данные. На бой их заливать не надо